# How to capture parameters after some string in commandline?

Tags: c, unix

How to capture a parameter after some string in command line?

```
./executable.out -apps path_to_out
```

In the above code I want to store path_to_out in a string variable. What is the efficient way of doing that?

Comment: In main:  std::string s = argv[2];

Comment: You're right.  const char *s = argv[2];

Comment: @walrii it can be more than one string before the argument path_to_out. In that case it will not be always argv[2]

Comment: Then perhaps you could please edit the question to provide a more complete description of the problem.  You could use the ancient getopt calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It kind of depends what kind of options you want. If you are willing to have only single-letter options, you can use the C library function `getopt` to parse the command line. If you would like long options (e.g., `--apps`), you can use `getopt_long`, but this is a GNU extension that will not port well. If you want really, really fancy option parsing, you can use something like GLib.

Of course, you can just roll your own, iterating over the arguments from 1 to `argc` and, when you encounter `-apps`, check that `i+1 < argc` and grab the next argument.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[argc-1]` already has the value for you if your path is the last argument in the command line.

if your main is like :

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
```

all the command line arguments are in `char **argv`.
in your case:
`argv[2]` is path_to_out.
if you want to copy it in a `string`,you can anyhow do this below thing:

```
string path(argv[2]);
```

Comment: argv[argc] is usually NULL or undefined.  Perhaps argv[argc-1]?

Comment: @sarathi It may not be last option every time. There may be a few more options after -apps in case of which I have to look for the argument after the option "-apps". One simple method I can think about is iterating till I get apps and grab next argument as told by apmasell below.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that by asking "after some string on the commandline" you are referring to the fact that the commandline argument `-apps` started with a dash, which makes it an "option".

The preferred way to doing this is to use a predefined library for processing options, such as [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) on GNU systems.

Answer (score 0):

when you run parameter store in this way..

Example:--->     ./executable.out -apps path_to_out

```
argv[0] will be "./executable.out"
argv[1] will be "-apps"
and argv[2] will be "path_to_out".
```

Comment: c not c++. I made the same mistake ;)